# Add dropdown list in the Excel sheet using C#

Tags: c#, excel

I am filling the Excel cells as row and column using C# in my entire project as given below. Now there is a new requirement to add a dropdownlist in the particular cell.

```
var oXl = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application {DisplayAlerts = false};
var oWb = oXl.Workbooks.Open(excelFileName);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet oSheet = oWb.Sheets[2];
oSheet.Cells[row, 1] = changeName + "\t";
oSheet.Cells[row, 2] = newName + "\t";
oSheet.Cells[row, 3] = (i + 1) + "\t";
oSheet.Cells[row, 4] = filename;
oSheet.Cells[row, 5] = type;
oSheet.Cells[row, 8] = dropdown; // Here I need to add a dropdown list
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First make a list for dropdown

```
        var list = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();
        list.Add("Charlie");
        list.Add("Delta");
        list.Add("Echo");
        var flatList = string.Join(",", list.ToArray());
```

then add this list as dropdown in the particular cell as below

```
var cell = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)oSheet.Cells[row, 8];
            cell.Validation.Delete();
            cell.Validation.Add(
               XlDVType.xlValidateList,
               XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertInformation,
               XlFormatConditionOperator.xlBetween,
               flatList,
               Type.Missing);

            cell.Validation.IgnoreBlank = true;
            cell.Validation.InCellDropdown = true;
```

Comment: it created the dropdown list but there is no default value in the dropdown

Comment: add default value like as cell.Value = "default value";

Comment: If you are quoting from another source, at least give credit to the original author: http://www.clear-lines.com/blog/post/Excel-In-Cell-DropDown-with-CSharp.aspx

Comment: @TotZam - no, not necessary. If you were to credit code reuse as a developer you'd be there all day. This is pretty bog-standard stuff.

Comment: I don't know if it used to be like this or if there is a mistake in the writing of the answer. Combining with "," doesn't work. ";" combining is necessary. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65697065/14875740

Comment: @OzgurSaklanmaz Combine with CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ListSeparator to avoid Locale issues (instead of , or ;)