# Read drop down values from excel using pandas

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, xlsx

I have a excel with a drop down cell. I have been trying to read the excel dropdown list but it only reads the selected option.

[image]

```
import pandas

df = pandas.read_excel("BQA.xlsx", header=0)
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()

print(df)
```

Output:

```
 Empty DataFrame
 Columns: [Column 1, Column 2, Column 3, Column 4, yes]
 Index: []
```

Expected Output:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Column 1, Column 2, Column 3, Column 4, [yes, no, yes1, no1]]
Index: []
```

Comment: This is an interesting question, hopefully someone will have answer. My gut says it not be available in python with xlrd etc. In .NET with excel-interop you want the cell validation property. see :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25659888/add-dropdown-list-in-the-excel-sheet-using-c-sharp . One suggestion which may still be fruitless would be to look at xlwings.

Comment: Storing a list in a cell is usually a bad enough idea, but it's really hard to work with one in a column.  Is there a saner storage method you'd settle for?

Comment: Ok, give me any method wherein I can read all the options of that cell

Comment: @ReKx not sure if you still care about this but what I did was store the lists of options in a dictionary then stored the keys to the options in the data frame.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `openpyxl` to extract the dropdown information: it's stored in the data_validations for a given sheet.  For example (newlines inserted for readability):

```
>>> wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("dropdown.xlsx")
>>> ws = wb["Sheet1"]
>>> ws.data_validations
<openpyxl.worksheet.datavalidation.DataValidationList object>
Parameters:
disablePrompts=None, xWindow=None, yWindow=None, count=1, 
dataValidation=[<openpyxl.worksheet.datavalidation.DataValidation object>
Parameters:
sqref=<MultiCellRange [E1]>, showErrorMessage=True, showDropDown=None, showInputMessage=True, 
allowBlank=False, errorTitle=None, error=None, promptTitle=None, prompt=None,
type='list', errorStyle=None, imeMode=None, operator=None, formula1='$L$4:$L$7', formula2=None]
```

I'm not going to handle all the possible cases, so this is just an example of the sorts of things you *could* do, but something like

```
def read_with_dropdown(book_name, sheet_name, range_str):
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(book_name)
    ws = wb[sheet_name]
    data = [[cell.value for cell in row] for row in ws[range_str]]

    validations = ws.data_validations.dataValidation
    for validation in validations:
        ranges = validation.sqref.ranges
        if len(ranges) != 1:
            raise NotImplementedError
        if validation.type == 'list':
            list_cells = ws[validation.formula1]
            values = [cell.value for cell_row in list_cells for cell in cell_row]
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError
        bounds = ranges[0].bounds
        try:
            data[bounds[1]-1][bounds[0]-1] = values
        except IndexError:
            pass
    return data
```

gives me (again, newlines inserted):

```
>>> data = read_with_dropdown("dropdown.xlsx", "Sheet1", "A1:E5")
>>> data
[['Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3', 'Column 4', ['yes', 'no', 'yes1', 'no1']],
 [None, None, None, None, None],
 [None, None, None, None, None],
 [None, None, None, None, None],
 [None, None, None, None, None]]
```

Comment: I get an error:                                                                                                             
 `---->        ranges = validation.sqref.ranges`
`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'ranges'`

Comment: Great answer, worked for me. Just had to remove your first `if, else` statement because my sheet had multiple ranges where there were drop down menus.

Comment: In my case all "list" type validations have  such `formula1` as "name6", "name8", "name19", etc...

Comment: Never mind! I've figured they're Defined Names. They define ranges in that case